# resize a series of images depending on the largest image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm struggling with a issue with my images. i have a series of images and i want to resize the m to fit is container based on the biggest one. preferably handled in jquery, javascript. there is an example below:
http://jsbin.com/bicupana/1/edit?html,css,js,output

So you see the images. The need to be resized proportionally, based on the largest image. i want the larges image to be filling 80% of it's parent, the body in this case. The reason why i'm struggling is that sometimes the width is bigger than the height and sometimes the height is bigger than the width.

The second reason i'm worried about is performance. If there are a lot of images, will people see the images flickering from big the the final size?

Comment: What did you tried? Please, share your JS code to review, you will not get a code for your need without publish no JS code.

Comment: What is your definition of the "largest" image? Width? Height? Total pixels (width x height)?